# Issue changing data types Java

Tags: java, types

This question seems to be very basic, but I don't know why, there is something wrong and I can't figure it out.

```
int [] concept = null; 
int i = 0; 
for (Iterator iterator = conceptsListGeneral.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {  
    Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) iterator.next();  
    String count = (String)map.get("count");  
//  concept[i] = new Integer(count).intValue();  
//  concept[i]= Integer.parseInt(count, 10);  
    Integer intObj2 = Integer.valueOf(count);  
    concept[i]= intObj2.intValue();  
    i++;
}
```

The comented lines are some of the thigs I have tried. I get a java.lang.NullPointerException on the last line.
By debugging, I know String count has a value, and olso Integer intObj2.
DOes anybody know why?? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please fix source code formatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just because your `concept` array is null. Replace your first line with

```
int[] concept = new int[conceptsListGeneral.size()]
```

and you'll have it working.

**EDIT**

Oh, and like Edwin says, don't forget to assign `i` a value.

Comment: `i` might not have a value, but mujer might also be asking for `Integer.valueOf(null);`  It's just too hard to tell without some idea of the values being passed around.  That's 3 possible issues on the same line, and the only solution would be to get a bit more of the code, or to have a few key `System.out.println(variable);` statements to actually report the value as it was at the time it was running.

Comment: Totally agree, but I was lucky to spot the issue the first. +1 to you

Answer (score 4):

--- edited to answer the specific question asked ---

You are pulling out a string, and the asking Integer to provide the integer value encoded in the string.

How do you know the String was not null?  Maybe the Map doesn't have a value for the specific key you asked.

How do you know that the concept array exists?  Maybe you should `System.out.println(...)` it to see it's object identifier.

How do you know the String contains characters which represent a number?  Maybe you are dealing with a string that doesn't have a corresponding int value?

In cases like these, it is often helpful to add a few 'System.out.println(...)' methods to make sure you are dealing with the same items you think you are dealing with.

Good luck.

--- original post follows ---

In assigning `concept[i]`, you must use the variable `i` to figure out which element of `concept` you wish to set.  Did you define it?  What is it's value?

Comment: The answer(s) are in there, the important part is to get you thinking about how to eliminate the possible problems.  That way you'll always get what you want in the future.

Comment: By debugging, I know String count has a value, and olso Integer intObj2.

Comment: Did you take a look at the value of `concept` in your debugger before you attempted to assign it's first element `concept[0]`?

Answer (score 1):

Create the int[] array.

```
int[] concept = new int[conceptsListGeneral.size()];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
System.out.println(count);
```

or your preferred logging framework to see if you're definitely getting *something* in your Map at key "count". Your results look consistent with that not being the case.

Plus of course you need to initialise your concept[] array.

Answer (score 0):

from the code you pasted you're concept array is still null. You need to initialize the concept array.

Answer (score 0):

i think you must first initialize your array with some dimension like "concept=new int[20]"

Answer (score 0):

You must define `concept` so it will have space for all elements you plan to put into it. According to your code, it must something like

```
int[] concept = new int[conceptsListGeneral.size()];
```

Answer (score 0):

You get a NullPointerException because your `concept` array is null. You need to initialize it :

```
int[] concept = new int[conceptsListGeneral.size()];
```